# Vaadin + Spring = lambda$0 + NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, lambda, vaadin

I have a problem with Vaadin ; this is my code :

```
@SpringView(name = LoginView.VIEW_NAME)
public class LoginView extends Panel implements View {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4440163925650357979L;

    public static final String VIEW_NAME = "login";

    @Autowired
    private UiController controller;

    public LoginView() {
        super();
        System.out.println(controller);
    }
}
```

And the exception is like :

```
2017-01-17 10:20:32.649 ERROR 10176 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler    : 

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.open.belgium.tonyrenard.vaadin.views.LoginView.lambda$0(LoginView.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
```

I'm not an expert with vaadin and I am totally lost. The dependences are ok ? I don't know...

It works and I change a point. Then, I rollback and it doesn't work anyway... Can you help me ?

EDIT : Controller is null and I don't understand why...

EDIT : I found the solution, my LoginView was not instantiated by Spring. Then, Spring will not instantiate the Controller. I have put off the new LoginView in the caller and the @Autowired works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Comment: Then you need to do some debugging and figure out at least what variable is null. See [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have edit the post for clearly reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, my LoginView was not instantiated by Spring.

Therefore, Spring will not instantiate the Controller.

I @Autowired the LoginView in the "caller" and the @Autowired for the Controller works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your button.

```
private Button connect = new Button();
```

Comment: No, it is no need to instanciate Button with vaadin declarative.

Comment: Your problem is that your button is null.

Comment: No, it is no need to instanciate Button with vaadin declarative.

Answer (score 0):

Something in this:

```
event -> {this.controller.entree(log.getValue(), pwd.getValue());}
```

is `null`. According to the stack trace, the only thing that can be null is `controller`. If it were `log` or `pwd`, then the `NullPointerException` would occur inside `UiController::entree`.

**EDIT**: I am wrong above, everything in this lamda can be null, including `log` and `pwd`. Assuming `controller` cannot be null because it is injected, then it has to be `log` or `pwd`.

Comment: "Autowired" or not, the stack trace says it's null. Why not add a log statement in your constructor and / or lamda to see if it's null or not?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am mistaken. Everything in the lamda can be null to cause that stack trace, not just `controller`. I will be editing my answer.

Comment: I have test the variables, you're right. The controller is null. But, Why ? I don't understand the reason.

Comment: I am not familiar with what `Autowired` does (or Spring in general, for that matter), but maybe something is wrong with your object dependencies?

Comment: @vagelis Sounds like you should look at [Why is my Spring Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null) then, as someone suggested an hour ago.

Comment: @khelwood Nope, doesn't sound like that at all. The OP's trouble was figuring out what caused the NullPointerException and that's what I addressed. He however, yes, should definitely take a look. :)

Comment: Thank you for the help. Bye